# Is it possible to add views on the Android ActionBar?

Tags: android, view, android-actionbar

It is possible to add my own customized controls(buttons, TextView, ImageView) on the ActionBar? I don't mean [ActionMenu items](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems) or [Action Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView).
On below Android4 versions I used 
`getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);`
where I could put any view I want, using `title_bar.xml`. But now I olso have `OptionsMenu` items on the title bar and I would like to add some extra customized views. Is it possible? If so, where can I define them and how can I access them from java code?

Comment: What is your specific problem with action views, since that seems to be what you want?

Comment: @CommonsWare But can I put whatever view I want using Action Views? I thought that I'm limited to use just some widgets provided by Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is possible to add my own customized controls(buttons, TextView, ImageView) on the ActionBar?

Use [action views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView) for stuff on the right and [`setCustomView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28int%29) for stuff in the left-to-middle (where the tabs and list navigation goes).

> But can I put whatever I want using Action Views?

They have to extend `android.view.View`. So you cannot put a `Boolean` in there.

Comment: `setCustomView()` does the job but only if you specify `getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);`, at least in my case.

Comment: @AlexAndro: Ah, right, I forgot to mention that step -- sorry.